# Are the following two inner products on differential forms equal?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, inner-products, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

There are two inner product on differential forms:

1. $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle$ induced from Riemannian metric $g$ by defining on 1-forms as dual of vector fields then extending to all differential forms i.e. $\langle e_{i_1}\wedge \dots\wedge e_{i_k}, e_{j_1}\wedge \dots\wedge e_{j_k}\rangle =\det[\langle e_{i_s}, e_{j_s}\rangle]$.
2. On compact oriented Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ $$(\alpha,\beta)=\int_M\alpha\wedge\star\beta.$$

**Q1:** Are these two inner products on differential forms equal?

**Q2:** If the answer to Q1 is "NO" then is it important to notice that two operators are adjoint of each other (or an operator is symmetric or self-adjoint)  w.r.t. which metric? e.g. $d$ and $\delta$ that are adjoint w.r.t. second inner product but I don't know it is w.r.t. other one.

Comment: How do you extend the first one to differential form?

Comment: @Didier: $\langle e_{i_1}\wedge \dots\wedge e_{i_k}, e_{j_1}\wedge \dots\wedge e_{j_k}\rangle =\det[\langle e_{i_s}, e_{j_s}\rangle]$. What's wrong?

Comment: Nothing's wrong, but you should state it in the question!

Comment: No, the first definition is *not*  on differential forms; it's pointwise or at best local. I suggest, however, that you relate $\alpha\wedge\star\beta$ *at a point* to the definition in 1.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Well, satisfying pointwise isn't that means that it is defined on diff forms?  I find this: $(\alpha,\beta)=\int_M\alpha\wedge\star\beta=\int_M\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle vol_g$. So this and your comment suggest (answer to Q1) that these two are different.

Comment: @TedShifrin: You meant it is defined on multi-covectors rather than on differential forms?

Comment: I think what @TedShifrin meant was that (1) is defined as an inner product on $\Lambda^p_xM$ for $x\in M$,  while (2) is defined as an inner product on $\Gamma(\Lambda^pM)$. The relation between (1) and (2) is that (2) is the **global** version of (1), obtained by integrating (1).

Comment: @Didier: $\Gamma(\Lambda^pM)$ is the $p$-forms $A^p(M)$ (or by another notation $\Omega^p(M)$)?

Comment: $\Gamma(\Lambda^pM)$ is the set of sections of the vector bundle $\Lambda^pM$, and is usually written as $\Omega^p(M)$ yes. Its elements are differential forms of degree $p$, and are global objects.

Comment: @Didier: So $\|\alpha\|_{(2)}(x)=\|\alpha\|_{(1)}(x)$?

Comment: There is no such thing as $\|\alpha\|_{(2)}(x)$ because $\|\alpha\|_{(2)}$ is a real number, and takes account of the whole behaviour of $\alpha$.

Comment: @Didier: I am confused a little. I think for any metric on a space $X$, one can measure the length of things at the given point but you say that not for $\|\alpha\|_{(2)}(x)$, that is reasonable here but this is against my first line.

Comment: What I said is that $(2)$ is not a Riemannian metric. It is an inner product on the vector space of $p$-forms. An analog would be the inner product on $L^2[0,1]$ defined by $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 fg$. There is no such thing as $\left(\int_0^1f^2\right)(x)$, because $\int_0^1f^2$ is a number, not a function.

Comment: @Didier: You meant "it is not a Riemannian metric over M" but it is over p-forms? yes?

Comment: The space of $p$-forms is a **vector space**. Of course, you can think of it as a manifold, but it is not interseting at all. An inner product on a vector space can be thought as a Riemannian metric but in a trivial way: all tangent spaces are canonically equal and the induced Riemannian metric is constant. Moreover, the points in this vector space are **not** the points of $M$, but are $p-$forms: you could not specialize at $x\in M$. Finally, $\|\alpha\|_{(2)}$ would be identified to a constant function... which make specialization at a point useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** the comment section is overgrowing so here is an answer that I hope will erase all your doubts.

**First part:**
As said in the comment section, $(1)$ is a inner product on the vector space $\Lambda^p_xM$ while $(2)$ is an inner product on the vector space $\Omega^p(M)$. The link between them is that $(2)$ is obtained by integrating $(1)$ over the whole manifold $M$.

An analog is this: consider the set $M=[0,1]$. Then for each $x\in [0,1], T_x[0,1] = \mathbb{R}$ and one can define an inner product on $T_x[0,1] = \mathbb{R}$ by $\langle a,b \rangle_x = a\times b$. This is $(1)$.

A vector field on $[0,1]$ is just a smooth function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, and $(2)$ is here
$$
\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(x) g(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 \langle f, g\rangle_x \mathrm{d}x.
$$

**Second part:**
If $V$ is a vector space and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an inner product, one can create a Riemannian metric on $V$, thought as a manifold the following way. As a vector space, the tangent bundle of $V$ is trivial:
$$TV = V\times V$$
and one can define the Riemannian metric $g_v = \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ for $v\in V$. It is a constant Riemannian metric because the canonical trivialization makes $g_v$ to be a function independant of $v \in V$.
Take $V = \Omega^p(M)$ and $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle = \int_M \alpha \wedge \star \beta$. Now, forget that $V$ and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is defined thanks to a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and just look at its structure: it is a vector space with an inner product. Hence, for this inner product $\|\alpha\|$ is a number.

If you really want to think of this construction as a Riemannian manifold, like in the first paragraph, then $\|\alpha\|$ will be a function:
$$
\|\alpha\| : \beta \in \Omega(M)^p \mapsto \|\alpha\|(\beta) = \|\alpha\|\in \mathbb{R} 
$$
which is constant and does not take points of $M$ as entries.

**Comment:** if you really do not understand what I said, here is just a question for you: for $x \in M$, how would you define $\left(\int_M \alpha\wedge \star \beta\right)(x)$?

This is the exact same thing as this question: how would you define $\left(\int_0^1 t^2 \mathrm{d}t\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$?